# RSS feed only shows last item

Tags: rss, feed, atom-feed

I have an RSS reader, and it only reads the last of the 3 items, and only shows that there is one item in it... it is always like 1/1... what could be wrong with my feed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had to adjust the RSS Feed layout a bit. Added times.